# SwiftUI equatable view optimization

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm following the steps in [this article](https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/01/22/optimizing-views-in-swiftui-using-equatableview/) to improve SwiftUI performance with custom diffing. For now, I'm just returning `true` in `==`:

```
struct MyView: View, Equatable {
   
   @ObservedObject var model: DataModel
   
   static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
       return true
   }

   var body: some View { ... lots of stuff ... }

}
```

I'm using `.equatable()` to wrap `MyView` in `EquatableView` where it's used.

However in the SwiftUI instrument, I still see the entire view rebuilt whenever `DataModel` changes. And the debugger confirms that `body` is called. `==` is also called.

My understanding is that `body` should not be called if `==` returns true when diffing. Is that correct?

How can I further investigate this?

Comment: Did you wrap your view into a `EquatableView`?

Comment: @Cristik yeah, using `.equatable()`

Comment: Having the exact same issue. I added a few prints in the `==` and in the `updateUIView` methods and having `.equatable()` has the same as not having it there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the view that conforms to Equatable without any dependencies like @ObservedObject. It should have plain properties.

Comment: That would be difficult because of all the bindings. Perhaps using Equatable isn't the right approach to optimize this.

Comment: I doubt this is the reason why the equatable view doesn't work, this is exactly why the SwiftUI added this concept: to allow rich views to signal when they should be rebuild and when not.

Comment: Actually this _is_ the way it works, dependencies like @ObservedObject will skip any equality checking or diffing and re-render, unfortunately.